# Custom HttpPost method CreateProduct is not hit from postman. i also add in webapiconfig file {action} at routing

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
        // GET api/values

        [HttpPost]
        public object CreateProduct([FromBody]AddProductRequestHandler value)
        {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Choose a nice headline, then ask the question and then add some more details.

Answer (score 0):

can you please share the details

and make sure you have define route for you api controller as mention below

[image]

The Global.asax.cs file in the project may require additional changes to enable ASP.NET Web API.

1. Add the following namespace references:

   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Routing;
2. If the code does not already define an Application_Start method, add the following method:

   protected void Application_Start()
   {
   }
3. Add the following lines to the beginning of the Application_Start method:

   GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);